# Google Plus sharing works but gives alert while sharing in apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus

I am working on iOS app and I am [following this guide](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started) for the Google+ iOS SDK.

When I click the share button the content will be shared but it gives an alert message as shown in below screenshot.

How can I avoid the alert?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not handle open url schema for this app

first you add in your plist (see attched image)
[image]

then add this method

```
- (BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application
            openURL: (NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication: (NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation: (id)annotation {
 return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url
               sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                      annotation:annotation];
}
```